Django - can't use different value and label with choicefield's list while using jQuery Editable Select
In Django I'm using a ChoiceField:
forms.py
class forms_sales_documents(forms.ModelForm):

    sales_documents_description_1 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=list(models_products.objects.values_list( 'id_product','product_denomination')), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'sales_documents_editable_select_description_1','style': 'width:200px','onchange': 'populate_selected_product(this.id,this.value)'}))

I'm using JQuery-Editable-select
https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select
to create searchable selectboxes but when I do, it becomes impossible to dissociate the ChoiceField value from the label.
They have to be the same like
models_products.objects.values_list( 'id_product','id_product'))

you can"t do something like
models_products.objects.values_list( 'id_product','product_denomination'))

otherwise the form won't save and raise the error :
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Anybody to help me on this ?

I found a workaround to get the selectbox value instead of the selectbox text if using something like :
models_products.objects.values_list( 'id_product','product_denomination'))

see my answer in this post
Get currently selected value in editable select box
I finally found a workaround.
When you apply the .editableSelect to a selectbox, it replace the initial selectbox with this in html :
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="your_defined_name" id="your_defined_id" style="width:200px" onchange="" class="es-input">

<ul class="es-list" style="top: 405px; left: 237.6875px; width: 200px; display: none;">
  <li value="1" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_1</li>
  <li value="2" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_2</li>
  <li value="3" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_3</li>
  <li value="4" selected="selected" class="es-visible selected">my_option_4</li>
  <li value="5" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_5</li>
  <li value="6" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_6</li>
  <li value="7" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_7</li>
  <li value="8" class="" style="display: none;">my_option_8</li>
</ul>

As you can see in my example, the selected option is the number 4.
The option selected has always a class call class="es-visible selected"
So what I found as a workaround is to find the <li> containing the class="es-visible selected" and get corresponding value:
editable_select_value = $('#my_editableSelect').val($('#my_editableSelect').parent().find($('[class*="es-visible"]')).val());

Then you can re-use the val wherever you need.
